# Mapear relação entre tabelas sem foreign key

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Tenho duas tabelas no postgresql:

**schema1.imovel**

```
idt_imovel  | int    
cod_imovel  | string
nome_imovel | string
etc...
```

**schema2.declaracao**

```
idt_declaracao | int
cod_imovel     | string
status         | string
etc...
```

As duas tabelas contém a coluna `cod_imovel` porém não existe um relacionamento entre as tabelas.
Eu tenho as duas tabelas mapeadas com hibernate, as classes `Imovel` e `Declaracao`.

Para cada entidade da classe `Imovel` preciso saber o status da declaração.

Existe alguma forma de "forçar" um relacionamento no hibernate mesmo sem o relacionamento existir no banco?

Preciso de algo do tipo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "imovel", schema = "schema1")

public class Imovel extends GenericModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name="idt_imovel")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "imovel_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "imovel_seq", sequenceName = "integracao_lotes.imovel_idt_imovel_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    public Integer id;

    @Column(name="nome_imovel")
    public String nomeImovel;

    @Column(name="cod_imovel")
    public String codigo; 

    @relacionamentofake //aqui precisa existir uma forma de mapear a tabela declaracao
    public Declaracao declaracao
```

Comment: No caso, para saber qual imóvel está relacionada a qual declaração, deve-se usar a coluna `cod_imovel`, certo? Além disso, edite sua pergunta e coloque a classe `Declaração` e diga qual é a cardinalidade do relacionamento, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Na teoria é possível, confesso que nunca tentei, mas não vejo motivos para o Hibernate não conseguir fazer o mapeamento sem a FK.

Como você precisa mapear a `Declaracao` no `Imovel`, você precisa usar alguma chave de `Declaracao` para o mapeamento. Presumo que possa usar `idt_declaracao`

Na entidade `Imovel`:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="idt_declaracao")
public Declaracao declaracao
```

E na entidade `Declaracao`:

```
@Column(name="idt_declaracao")
public Integer id;
```